# TextArea como en Whatsapp

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, textarea

¿Cómo lograr el mismo efecto que usa Whatsapp para poner entre dos mismos símbolos un efecto al enviar?
Por ejemplo,

- Negrita * Text *
- Cursiva ~ Text ~
- Tachado _ Text _

Que al convertir * Este es un texto *
Te pueda leer como  **Este es un texto**

Comment: Buenas padrón, te invito a pasar por [ask] para ver como elaborar una pregunta de calidad, en StackOverflow tendemos a ayudar con problemas específicos sobre el código, ¿Has intentado algo? Te invito a editar tu pregunta para poder añadir lo que hayas intentado para tener una base sobre la que trabajar y así poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco confusa, ¿Deseas que sea texto enriquecido en que lugar? ¿HTML? ¿Consola?